# Best way to define optional query parameters

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access

We have an Access database which uses forms to specify parameters for a query for a report.

We want the parameters to be optional, so the user can leave them blank to specify 'All'.

Now we've done this for years using the following syntax for these criteria:

```
Like [Forms]![ReportForm]![Customer] & "*"
```

The trouble with the above way of doing this is if the Customer code is actually a prefix of another code. For instance, if you have Customer codes "AB" and "ABCD", and you choose Customer "AB" from the drop-list, you get both the "AB" and the "ABCD" Customer data.

One way to overcome this would be to use the following format for the criteria:

```
Like iif([Forms]![ReportForm]![Customer] is null, "*" [Forms]![ReportForm]![Customer])
```

But that's getting quite complex.

Is there a better way to do this?

---

EDIT: We would prefer to do this using the Query builder (Design View) as our users are not great with the SQL view. Also, there are currently 4 of these optional parameters on the Form for requesting this report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are finding out, putting forms! expressions in queries can get really messy real fast.

Even worse, is now that the query is now "married" and attached to that ONE form. Often, I have a nice query that I could use MANY times for different reports, and often even that same query could be used for reports. However the INSTANT you place a forms! expression that means the query is ONLY good when that form is opened.

Worse, is very hard to control things like having 5 combo boxes, but the user only selects restrictions in 3 of the combo boxes...and wants the other 2 to be ignore.

So, the solution use now is simply to take the values from the form, and build your own where clause in code. That way, you simply design the reports (or forms), and attached them to the query, BUT NO FORMS! conditions are placed in the query.

To "send" the conditions to the report (or form), you simply use the "where" clause. This is exactly why ms-access has this feature and it solves a zillion problems…and will reduce your development costs by a substantial amount.

So you code like this:

```
dim   strWhere       as string

 ' select sales rep combo

if isnull(cboSalesRep) = false then

   strWhere = "SalesRep = " & cboSalesRep & ""

end if

 ‘ select what City for the report

if isnull(cboCity) = false then
    if strWhere <> "" then
        strWhere = strWhere " and "
    end if
    strWhere = strWhere & "City = " & cobCity & ""
end if
```

Note how the 2nd combo test is setup. You can add as "many" more conditions you want. Lets say we have a check box to only include Special Customers. We can add to our very nice prompt screen a check box to

[x] Show Only Special customers

The code we add would be:

```
if chkSpeicalOnly = True then
    if strWhere <> "" then
        strWhere = strWhere " and "
    end if
    strWhere = strWhere & "SpecialCust  =  true"
end if
```

For sure, each combo and control we add to the nice report screen takes a bit of code, but no more messy then the query builder and this way, each query is nice and clean, and free of a bunch of HIGHLY un-maintainable forms! expressions.

Further, it means you can re-use the same query for different reports, and have no worries about some form that is supposed to be open. So, a tiny bit more code eliminates the messy query problem. This bit of coding is thus a very worth while trade and solves the optional issue by simply elimination of the hard coded parameters.

More important is "over" time you can easy modify and add MORE options - just add the above bit of code for each additional control on the form you want to use for the "where" clause.

Comment: Thank you for showing me the light! As a programmer I can appreciate this way of doing things. Up until now I have had to come along after the fact and support these form/query/reports after the 'power users' have gone so far and got stuck. Time for me to step in and make this a programming task instead. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I often use queries like this:

```
WHERE
(tbl_Table1.Field1=[Forms]![ReportForm]![Filter1] Or [Forms]![ReportForm]![Filter1] is Null) AND
(tbl_Table1.Field2=[Forms]![ReportForm]![Filter2] Or [Forms]![ReportForm]![Filter2] is Null) AND
(tbl_Table1.Field3=[Forms]![ReportForm]![Filter3] Or [Forms]![ReportForm]![Filter3] is Null) AND
...
```

Unfortunately Access "optimizes" quite simple SQL constructions like this to hard-to-read presentation in query builder, but if you have 1-2 filters only, it will be readable